# Spring Boot - mapping Entities from external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, spring-data

I am having some trouble with Spring Boot, Spring Data and having Entities in an external jar. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Sprint Data repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MyFileRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyFile, Long> {

   @Modifying
   @Transactional
   @Query("Delete from MyFile f where f.created < ?1")
   long deleteOldEntities(Date cutoffDate);
}
```

My entity, which is in another jar entirely looks like this:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(
   name = "SequenceIdGenerator",
   sequenceName = "SEQ_ID_MY_FILE",
   allocationSize = 20
)
@Table(
   name = "MYFILE_TABLE"
)
public class MyFile extends BaseEntity {

   private long id;  
   private byte[] data;
   [...]

   public MyFile() {}

   @Id
   @Column(
      name = "id",
      nullable = false
   )
   @GeneratedValue(
      generator = "SequenceIdGenerator"
   )
   public long getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   [...]
```

}

And the BaseEntity looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    private Date created = null;
    private Date updated = null;

    public BaseEntity() {}

    @Column(
       name = "created"
    )
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getCreated() {
        return this.created == null?null:new Date(this.created.getTime());
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
    if(created != null) {
        this.created = new Date(created.getTime());
    }

}
```

So, when I try to run this code I get a long stacktrace which basically ends with:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyFile is not mapped [Delete from MyFile f where f.created < ?1]
```

I believe that this may have something to do with the Spring Boot Configuration. The external jar does not have and @SpringBootApplication anywhere. It is basically just a jar with all my Entities.

My application jar however has this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("myapp.service.dao.entity") --> This is the package where all my entities are located. 
public class CommonApplication {

}
```

What is my error?

Comment: See the most popular answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504824/loading-jpa-entity-from-external-jar-file

Looks like you have to specify the jar file name in persistence.xml

Comment: Right, but the whole point with spring boot is that there is no xml-config. I would have thought that the @EntityScan would be enough.

Comment: @benbjo Did you solve this problem? I'm setting up a Spring boot app but I'm unable to load entities from an external JAR

Answer (score 1):

To scan entities residing in jar, you have to set packagesToScan field of LocalSessionFactory.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    localSessionFactory
            .setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"myapp.service.dao.entity", "com.application.entity"});
    return localSessionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working using by using the following bean to set the packages scan:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("add packages here");
    return factory.getObject();
}
```